# Javascript on a PHP Platform?

Tags: php, javascript

I was once in a conversation with a graphic designer who was asserting that PHP is far and away the most prevalent scripting language in use on the web. I challenged this saying that [in my limited knowledge] javascript was used in more places.

The response I got was, "OK, sure, javascript, but used on a PHP platform."

I was, and still am, puzzled by this response, and can't figure out any possible meaning to this statement, though I have little subject matter expertise. Does the above statement make any sense, or have any truth to it?

Comment: javascript runs in a browser, PHP runs on a webserver.... you can run something like nodejs on a webserver, but it's not common

Comment: What he meant was "A backend language (like PHP)"

Comment: PHP is a server-side script. JavaScript has been client side (in the browser), although it is getting popular server-side.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). We cannot answer vague, open-ended questions.

Comment: I would ascribe limited importance to a graphic designer's opinions about software technology.

Comment: Virtually every web page must use javascript on the front end but has a choice in the backend. This is a no-brainer.

Comment: Sense? Some, not a lot. True? Some, not a lot. Relevance? Some, not a lot. Language pissing wars are pointless (other then remembering that PHP is awful ;) ).

Comment: `I was once in a conversation with a graphic designer ` Am I evil, if I giggled here, after seeing the title?

Comment: The graphic designer has no idea what he's talking about. That being said this question is not a good fit for [SO], and as such I have voted to close it.

Comment: Reference material that should put an end to petty language debates like this: http://www.brandonsavage.net/languages-dont-matter/ and http://michaelkimsal.com/blog/tech-partisanship-doesnt-help-much/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do different things. Javascript makes your frontend dynamic, while PHP makes your backend dynamic. I'm honestly not up to speed with my statistical knowledge, but I'd opt that both are quite far spread. Javascript is absolutely dominant in the front-end, mostly because there isn't really an alternative. JS runs on every browser, while other scripting solutions don't really.

On the backend, you're more flexible. PHP, Ruby (on RAILs), Python, Java, even javascript (node.js) are examples for backend scripting that come to mind right away.

Comment: Rails is an MVC framework. It is not the only way to use Ruby on the server.

Comment: I know, there are also a lot of other solutions. I completely left out all the propriatary MS stuff for example. It's just what I could come up with right awa ;)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your friend meant that Javascript (a client side scripting language that does not depend on the server environment), is placed in web pages on server platforms which also support PHP (a server side language).

It's a bit of a nonsensical argument, likening it to whether phones are as popular as televisions. They both do different things and have different applications, although the two can often interact.